# deployed outlook addin 2007 not loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, add-in, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

This is my first addin project and I have a huge problem.

I created an addin project and it's working fine on the development computer, but when I deployed it to the test computer the addin doesn't display the new command bar and button, but it is located in the 'active addins'.
I made a project setup as they say in the Microsoft MSDN, added a registry entry as they said and followed all the basic steps, so why is the addin working fine when it is deployed on my computer, but not on the test computer?
The addin project is for Outlook 2007 and I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: welcome to the OL addin fan club :) - lookup the registry (I'm not close, talking from memory) which tells you the state of the add-in (though that should be ok - but you might need to reset that anyway - I think the '3' is the winner). It often marks your add-in if previous failed attempts. Also another to throw in there - is OL requires VSTO libs (if you're using that?), are you on dev or other machine. There are many more issues though